# Формирование запроса к MS SQL - ошибка в преобразовании типа данных

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2

При формировании запроса к MS SQL возникает ошибка в преобразовании типа данных `character string to uniqueidentifier`
Пытаюсь сделать запрос к базе данных, но получаю ошибку. Делаю всё по [инструкции](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#executequery).

**Ошибка**:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to
>   uniqueidentifier

**Код запроса**:

```
$queryValueData = 'SELECT ETA_Employee_id as eta_id, GroupSort as gs, MeasureName as mn, MeasureSort as ms, Value as value
    FROM
        EO_TS
    WHERE 
        TS_employee_id IN (:ids)
        AND Date BETWEEN :ds AND :df
        AND TableName = :tableName
    ORDER BY
        ETA_Employee_id, GroupSort, MeasureSort';

$valueData = $conn->executeQuery(
    $queryValueData,
    array(
        'ids' =>$tsIds,
        'ds' => $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00.000000 +02:00'),
        'df' => $date->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59.000000 +02:00'),
        'tableName' => $tableName,
    ),
    array(\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY)
);
```

Если передавать вместо `IN` одно значение, то запрос отрабатывает успешно. 
Так же пытался уточнять тип через параметры, но результат так же не получил.
Менял следующее значение с

> \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY

на

> $type = \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getType('guid');

[Ссылка на описание Типов и их карта](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#id42).

В массиве $tsIds хранятся данные следующего формата:

> 83176DA0-C808-48D7-B802-3A2ADE61740A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо указать к какому параметру относится тип массив строк: `'ids' => \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY`.

В итоге получим:

```
$valueData = $conn->executeQuery(
    $queryValueData,
    array(
        'ids' =>$tsIds,
        'ds' => $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00.000000 +02:00'),
        'df' => $date->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59.000000 +02:00'),
        'tableName' => $tableName,
    ),
    array('ids' => \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY)
);
```